# tcpdump - prevent interpreting/decoding protocols

Tags: tcpdump, protocol

Is there a way to stop `tcpdump` from (mis)interpreting protocols in captured packets?

It assumes that traffic coming from port 4500/udp is always IPSec traffic, 53/udp is DNS query, etc and tries to decode it. That's a problem for me because I can't parse the output properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the '-q' option to remove the content decoding. You can maybe add the '-A' to see in ASCII the content of the packets, or -dd to see in C format.

Comment: You might also try the `-nn` flag to prevent host and port name resolution.